# Use result of a rails where query for another query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm curious if there is an easy way to archive this query:

`SomeTable.where(value_b: SomeTable.where(value_a: 1).pluck(:value_b))`

For an example, if we have:

```
    SomeTable
    |id |    a    |   b    |
    |1  |    1    |   2    |
    |2  |    2    |   2    |
    |3  |    3    |   3    |
    |4  |    4    |   4    |
```

And the user enter number `1` into the system, I want to be able to find value of `b` where value of `a = 1`, which is `2`. Then use this value of `b` to find all the records with this value.

So, I want to be able to use `1` and extract SomeTable with id: 1 and 2

Thanks!

Comment: you can us join

Comment: can you please post the exact schema

Comment: Yes. Please post the exact schema. The one you posted doesn't make any sense because  `SomeTable.where( value_a: 1 )`  will give you the same result as `SomeTable.where(value_b: SomeTable.where(value_a: 1).pluck(:value_b)) `

Comment: Sorry I don't think I can post the exact schema, Its way too large. 
@LarsonB, `SomeTable.where( value_a: 1 )` doesn't give `SomeTable` with id 2

Comment: Change that `pluck` to a `select` and ActiveRecord will use a subquery.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SomeTable.joins("JOIN some_table as replica on replica.value_b = some_table.value_b")
         .where(replica: {value_a: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeTable.where("b in (SELECT b FROM some_tables where a = ?)", a_value)
```

a_value is your 'a' value to find 'b' value